# Creating dynamic emberjs model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm developing a client application in ember that connects to a RESTful API. The thing is that the client wants the API to be able to insert new fields on the Database. The prboem is that  in ember I need to denfine the model beforehand with its attributes.

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow define a dynamic model, where it connects with the API which will return a JSON with the model structure, namely fields and its datatype and then create the model on the fly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am looking for something similar too. There is a JSON backend that could have different content_item_types for different clients, and we are building a single page Ember App that can serve all customers. Say customer A could have content_item_types - books and movies. While customer B could have countries and continents. / So, is there a way to create Ember Models on the fly?!